# Is there a way to update the data inside the application? Without updating the entire application?

Tags: android

I'm trying to build an application, "Journal for Drivers".
I would like to add new information to the driver in this application. This information will be in text format (or text with images)

My question is, if I want to add a news update to the application, a news for drivers, can it be solved for example by some storage on a server, where the application automatically downloads this news? Or do I have to write the entire app in Android Studio and update the original version of the app?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean, or that there is any specific programming question being asked. Define "the content of the application" vs "the entire application".

Comment: Query updated. @Jon

Comment: Muuuuch clearer. Great job rewording!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three main ways to accomplish this:

1. You can create a webpage and use webview component to load this website in your application. In this case you will have full control on the data (backend) while you can change the ui of this webview on the fly without releasing new versions of your application. called also hybrid application (which is part native you still need to create apk with this webview) and web part which will be where most of your code exists.
2. You can create a native application which will be written in native only (java or kotlin) in this way you will need to release a new version every time you will change anything in your application. (including logic change or ui change).
3. You can create PWA project which will simulate a "native" application in this way you control 100% of the code and it will based on web. You can open a url on your mobile browser and you could "install" a mobile version of the webpage on your mobile device which will simulate a "native" application it also other platforms such as iOS, windows and Mac (if I'm not mistaken)

Comment: Thank you for exhausting answer. Thank you very much. @DemoDemo

Answer (score 0):

This can achieved via an endless number of strategies. One such strategy uses deep links along with an API for this. For this to work, you will need to set up an online server which will serve as a back end. This is where you will post your news updates to an endpoint or endpoints. This can be implemented in many ways. For example, you may just hardcode your updates to the html, or more likely you will store each article to some sort of db. When a user of the app goes to view an article, it will send an HTTP request to the server asking for the article. The server will then retrieve said article from the db, process it in whatever way needed, and send it back to your app.

Using this method, you only need to change your article on the back end (or better yet add  your article to db and update a pointer that points to current article).

Comment: Look into "deep links" in Android. These will let you pull up any web page from inside your app. Also, your api isnt restricted to pulling only web pages. You can store and retrieve your articles' text in JSON format, along with related resources such as images, on your server and then process that raw JSON data from inside your Android app. In fact, this is most likely the way that I would do it.

Comment: Thank you for your tip.@Nathan Toulbert.